# Python Programming if Statement issue

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project exercise which involves me creating a program that will assess children's arithmetic capabilities. It asks addition, multiplication and subtraction questions and it is written in Python.

You can see the code below for yourself.

```
from random import randint

username = input("What is your name? ")
score = 0
question = 1



while (question < 11):
    random_integer= randint(1,3)
    if (randnum == 1):
        return = multiply()
    elif (randnum == 2):
        return = add()
    else:
        return = subtract()

    if (return== True):
        score+=1
    question += 1

input("\nYou scored %s out of 10... \nPress enter to quit" %(score))

def multiply():
    num1= randint(1,12)
    num2= randint(1,12)
    correct_ans= str(num1 * num2)

    user_answer = input("%s x %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False


def add():
    num1= randint(1,50)
    num2= randint(1,50)
    correct_ans = str(num1 + num2)

    user_answer = input("%s + %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False

def subtract():
    num1= randint(1,80)
    num2= randint(1,50)
    correct_answer = str(num1 - num2)

    user_answer = input("%s - %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False
```

Now, when I run the program, the first line that asks for the user's name appears normally, but then this block of code appears as an error in IDLE. 
Can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\code3.py", line 14, in <module>
return = subtract()
NameError: name 'subtract' is not defined
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters my apologies, I was looking at the wrong code. Here is the updated traceback!

Comment: You cannot use `return =`, that's not valid Python syntax. I'm surprised you got a `NameError` there rather than a `SyntaxError` exception.

Comment: And your `while` loop is executed *before you defined your functions*. Move it to *below* the functions instead.

Comment: "Now, when I run the program, the first line that asks for the user's name appears normally" -> Your code does not prompt for the username. edit: at least not the part you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Well `return` is a reserved key word, so just changing the variable names should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your code.

The first thing is that you have to define a function *before* you use it. So the error "NameError: name 'subtract' is not defined" you got, is because this function is not defined at this state in the code. The solution is to move up your definition of the functions.

The next thing is that you have wrote "return = x". That is not correct python syntax. If you want to return a value, use "return x".

The last thing (I mentioned) is that you use "input()". In your code you have to use "raw_input()", because the rest of your code expects a string.

I have corrected these things in your code (and some other little things).

```
from random import randint

username = raw_input("What is your name? ")
score = 0
question = 1
answerCorrect = True

def multiply():
    num1= randint(1,12)
    num2= randint(1,12)
    correct_ans= str(num1 * num2)

    user_answer = raw_input("%s x %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False


def add():
    num1= randint(1,50)
    num2= randint(1,50)
    correct_ans = str(num1 + num2)

    user_answer = raw_input("%s + %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False

def subtract():
    num1= randint(1,80)
    num2= randint(1,50)
    correct_ans = str(num1 - num2)

    user_answer = raw_input("%s - %s = " %(num1, num2))
    if (user_answer == correct_ans):
        print("Correct")
        return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer was %s" %(correct_ans))
        return False

while (question < 11):
    random_integer= randint(1,3)
    if (random_integer == 1):
        answerCorrect = multiply()
    elif (random_integer == 2):
        answerCorrect = add()
    else:
        answerCorrect = subtract()

    if (answerCorrect== True):
        score+=1
    question += 1

raw_input("\nYou scored %s out of 10... \nPress enter to quit" %(score))
```

Comment: The point with input() is just needed for python 2.x. If you use python 3.x input() is ok.